# Update linked file in photoshop via java

Tags: javascript, photoshop

I am trying to write a script that will go through every smart object and essentially do the same thing as if I were to open it and then hit the "Layer>Smart Objects> update all modified content". My goal is to create a script that will iterate over every smart object within every smart object; effectively updating all the smart objects recursively.

For example, say I have a single .png that is an image of a pebble. I created a linked smart object out of that, then made some duplicates, then make smart-objects from those, made duplicates of those pebble groups, etc. until I had a mountain. The idea of my script is to iterate through every nested smart object down to that single pebble and update the linked content; so If I change my pebble, I can run the script to then update the entire mountain. Does that make sense?

Here lies my problem though: I am very new to photoshop javascript, and I don't know where to even start with this. ideally I want to loop through the layers, open each smart object found in them, do whatever it takes to update the linked content, then repeat that on all the objects within that object, etc.

i know some c#; and if i was coding this in c# it'd be a foreach loop function that calls itself foreach smart object, like this pseudo code:

```
void updateeverything(document)
{
     foreach(layer OBJ in document)
     {
       //magic happens on this line to do the same thing as the "update changed content" button in the UI
       if(OBJ.type().tostring() == "smartobject")
        {
          updateeverything(OBJ)
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Java and Javascript are two different languages. Changing tag to Javascript

Comment: Hello @Fennecai, Below is the link to the photoshop scripting that may help you to start the process. If you can explain what exactly you want I mean with some examples, I can help you by the script too.

Comment: Link to the script reference - https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/photoshop/pdfs/photoshop-cc-javascript-ref-2019.pdf